# Quarkus: MicroProfile metrics and Graphite

Tags: jboss, graphite, quarkus, microprofile

Is there a way to send microprofile metrics to graphite directly? The only guide with Quarkus I've found is this https://quarkus.io/guides/microprofile-metrics. I'm looking for something similar to what I'm using with Spring Boot https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/graphite. Do we have the same thing but in the Quarkus context (with native image support)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The micrometer extension is recommended for metrics, and it has support for Graphite via a quarkiverse extension:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.micrometer.registry</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-graphite</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the quarkus issue that people can follow and give feedback https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10525